# Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call() vs Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()

Tags: javascript, oop, call

In my JavaScript code I have a function which contains following set of statements

```
function someFunc(object,action){
                    for(var property in object){
                        if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property)){
                            //TODO
                        }
                    }
                }
}
```

and If I replace *if statement* inside function with

```
if(obj.hasOwnProperty(property)){
    //TODO
    }
```

both are working fine for me. All I want to know is that which among them is better approach and why? I know that `obj.hasOwnProperty(property)` check for the personal property of the object. I also want to know how call is chaining up here

`object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property)`

Comment: If the object for this or that reason hasn't got a way to access Object.prototype (normally all objects have) you might choose use the first method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would generally always go with `obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)`.

There's less indirection and it'll be much clearer for others trying to read and understand your code. It'll also run slightly faster, because you don't need to rebind the context for `this`.

I can't think of many pitfalls that would *require* you to use the other approach.

- If `obj` inherits from `null` not `Object.prototype`
- If `hasOwnProperty` has been redeclared on `obj`
- If `hasOwnProperty` has been redeclared in `obj`'s prototype chain

All of these scenarios are pretty rare in day to day applications and if you do find one of them, it's safest, easiest and best to fix the problem there, rather than use the more defensive `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call` form.